# Programatically insert variables into string.format ( C# )

Tags: c#

so imagine this, I have the following variable set to a string.format:

```
string foo = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8}");
```

the Format method will have a lot more placeholders than this (64 to be precise) and depending on some conditions they could change. so I was wondering if there was a way to loop through a list of variables I have and then insert those variables into the format method correspondingly. I have no idea how to even start this and if it's even possible, but surely I don't have to manually insert 64 variables into the format method?

Comment: After three parameters, `string.Format` will use the overload that takes an object array (declared with `params` keyword). So just stick all your variables in an `object[]` and pass that.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: Put all of your variables in an object array and pass that. `var args = new object[] { var1, var2,...} ; string.Format("...",args);`

Comment: If you have 64 placeholders in the format string then you need to pass 64 variables. I fails to see where is the difference If you write them directly in the string.Format call or if you build an array with 64 variables.

Comment: do you mean to join a list of variables `string foo = string.Join("|", list);` ?

Comment: @Steve not only would that look messy, the positions of the variables will change and a lot more will be happening so I would rather be able to sort them and position them as I would like and also have cleaner code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload of `String.Format` that accepts a `params object[]` parameter:

```
public static string Format (string format, params object[] args);
```

This means that you can pass any number of any type of objects that you want. You are, however, responsible for ensuring that the amount of parameters passed match the number of placeholders in the string. For example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
int number = 1234;
string format1 = "{0} == {1}";

string formatted = Format(format1, date, number);
// OR
object[] values = new object[] { date, number };
string formatted = Format(format1, values);

private static string Format(string text, params object[] values)
{
    return string.Format(format1, values);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the length of `args` is different than the number of placeholders in the `format` string. In fact this will cause an exception if there are not enough elements in `args`.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's why the disclaimer "You are, however, responsible for ensuring that the amount of parameters passed match the number of placeholders in the string" in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Get a list, sort it in the order you want - then

```
var l = new List<string>();
// add to l, in the order you want then - 
// when adding convert to the string equivalent if it's not a string already.
var s = string.Join("|",l);
return s;
```

Comment: that's not what i meant, the "|" are there for no reason to be honest.

Comment: I guess I'm not following - you could just do var s = string.Join(" ",l);

Answer (score -1):

yes, possible. you can create a function with unspecified number of parameters using the `params` keyword. something like this:

```
void myFunction(params object[] parameters)
{
    foreach (var x in parameters) ...

}
```

Comment: how would I insert those parameters into the string.Format method

Comment: if you could make that clearer in the answer please so that I can mark the question as accepted